# Why am I getting the 'referenced before assignment' error?

Tags: python, tkinter

This code is the start of a pool scoreboard. It works up until I press the button and then it comes up with a traceback saying 'referenced before assignment'. Here is the full code although you probably won't need it  all:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox as box

window = Tk()
window.configure(bg = 'white')
frame_stripes = Frame(window, bg = 'white')
frame_spots = Frame(window, bg = 'white')

stripes = 7
spots = 7
stripe_fouls = 0
spot_fouls = 0

def another_go():
    box.showinfo('Another Go', 'You get another go')
def foul_2_gos():
    box.showinfo('Extra Go', 'Your opponent gets 2 goes')

def stripes_pot():
    stripes -= 1
    another_go()
stripes_plus = Button(frame_stripes, text = 'Stripes Pot', command = stripes_pot)

def stripes_foul_add():
    stripes_fouls += 1
    foul_2_goes()
stripes_foul = Button(frame_stripes, text = 'Stripes Foul', command = stripes_foul_add)

def spots_pot():
    spots -= 1
    another_go()
spots_plus = Button(frame_spots, text = 'Spots Pot', command = spots_pot)

def spots_foul_add():
    spots_fouls += 1
    foul_2_goes()
spots_foul = Button(frame_spots, text = 'Spots Foul', command = spots_foul_add)

stripes_plus.pack()
spots_plus.pack()
stripes_foul.pack()
spots_foul.pack()

frame_stripes.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)
frame_spots.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

window.mainloop()
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dylan.DESKTOP-7RLU752\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Dylan.DESKTOP-7RLU752\Desktop\Pool Score Counter.py", line 26, in stripes_foul_add
    stripes_fouls += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'stripes_fouls' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback in your question, we don't want to try and guess what line caused this error.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille sorry, I'll remember that for next time.

Comment: There is still time to edit your question to include the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you did not specify that the variables should be used globally. You can do this, by modifying your functions as follows:

```
def stripes_pot():
    global stripes
    stripes -= 1
    another_go()
stripes_plus = Button(frame_stripes, text = 'Stripes Pot', command = stripes_pot)

def stripes_foul_add():
    global stripes_fouls
    stripes_fouls += 1
    foul_2_goes()
stripes_foul = Button(frame_stripes, text = 'Stripes Foul', command = stripes_foul_add)

def spots_pot():
    global spots
    spots -= 1
    another_go()
spots_plus = Button(frame_spots, text = 'Spots Pot', command = spots_pot)

def spots_foul_add():
    global spots_fouls
    spots_fouls += 1
    foul_2_goes()
spots_foul = Button(frame_spots, text = 'Spots Foul', command = spots_foul_add)
```

That said, using global variables isn't always a great idea. For your project a class-based implementation would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `stripes` before the functions and then referred to it inside the functions but inside each function you have to declare that you want to use the global variable `stripes` by adding `global stripes`. You should do this for each variable that causes an exception.

```
stripes = 7

def stripes_pot():
    global stripes
    stripes -= 1
    another_go()
```